# Does variable_get() first go to 'variable' table in the database or the $conf array in settings.php?

Tags: configuration

I can't tell from the source for `variable_get()` for Drupal 6 whether it first looks for something in the variable table in the database, or the `$conf` array in settings.php.

Also, if I were to add something in some code to the `$conf` array, would I need to do anything in order for variable_get to see it?

```
global $conf;
$conf['myvalue'] = 'newvalue';
```

If 'myvalue' were set to 'oldvalue' in settings.php, then what would I need to do in order for `$conf['myvalue']` to now return newvalue instead of oldvalue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function that is responsible for loading the values of the Drupal variables in memory is [variable_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/variable_init/6), which executes the following code:

```
  if ($cached = cache_get('variables', 'cache')) {
    $variables = $cached->data;
  }
  else {
    $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {variable}');
    while ($variable = db_fetch_object($result)) {
      $variables[$variable->name] = unserialize($variable->value);
    }
    cache_set('variables', $variables);
  }

  foreach ($conf as $name => $value) {
    $variables[$name] = $value;
  }
```

`$conf`, the value passed to the function from [_drupal_bootstrap()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap/6) is the array read from the settings.php file. The function that reads the configuration file is [conf_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/conf_init/6), which is called from `_drupal_bootstrap()` before calling `variable_init()`.
As you see in the code, the values read from the database are then overwritten with the values find in the `$conf` array.

Similar code is present in Drupal 7 (see [drupal_bootstrap()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7), [_drupal_bootstrap_configuration()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_configuration/7), and [_drupal_bootstrap_variables()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--bootstrap.inc/function/_drupal_bootstrap_variables/7)).

The only way to use the value read from the database is to remove the value set in settings.php.